# The use of async with Koa

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand how to use Koa.

https://github.com/unixfox/pupflare/blob/master/index.js

The above example uses something like the following.

```
(async () => {
...
    app.use(async ctx => {
```

But the following Koa tutorial does not show this usage.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/koajs/koajs_quick_guide.htm

Why are these structures necessary? When is it essential to use them?

Comment: There is no relationship between `async` and [Koajs](https://koajs.com/), In mentioned Github code, Used [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). You can only use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function only.

Comment: So if the async is used because await is used in `{...}` of `(async () => { .. })`? If I delete all `await` in `{}`, I can delete `async`?

Comment: Yes, if you removed `await` then you can remove `async` as well,

Comment: This requirement is unreasonable in this case. That is impossible for me to minimize it as I don't understand how it works in the first place. If I knew it, I wouldn't have this question. For a reproducible example, just copy the code in the link that I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated arleady in the comments, the `async/await` pattern is nothing that is related to `koa`. This is a pattern that was added to ECMAScript 2017.

Imagine you have something like this: e.g. a promise function that gets data from your database. You would probably write it this way:

```
app.use(ctx => {
    getData().then(data => {
        ctx.body = data;    
    });
})
```

The idea behind the `async/await` pattern is, that you can write async code without the need to make callbacks or the use of `.then(...)`.

`await` can be put in front of any async promise-based function to pause your code on that line until the promise fulfills, then return the resulting value. This works only inside a function that is anotated with `async`

So with this pattern, your code could look like this:

```
app.use(async ctx => {
    data = await getData();
    ctx.body = data;
})
```

Now the code is a little bit more readable. Just imagine more complex code, here it can really make a huge difference.